# Do densities of invariant distributions satisfy the Fokker Planck equation?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $\{X_t\}_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ is a $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued homogenous diffusion process with drift vector $b$ and diffusion matrix $A$. Is it ever true that if the process has an invariant distribution with a density $\pi(x)$, then $\pi$ is a time independent solution of the Fokker Planck equation, that is

$$0=-\sum_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}[b_i(x)\pi(x)]+\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}[A_{i,j}(x)\pi(x)]?\quad\quad(*)$$

I've spend a bit of time scanning through standard references  (Freidman, Oskendal, Karatzas-Shreve, Arnold) looking results connecting the densities of invariant distributions to one of the Kolmogorov equations and I've had little success. The closest I've gotten is a couple of results in Section 31 of [these notes](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.tifr.res.in%2F~publ%2Fln%2Ftifr64.pdf&ei=EjSOUofEDcOw7Abg0oCgCQ&usg=AFQjCNE0DEk00dUM0a_32Bp4mzYXTS7zDg&bvm=bv.56988011,d.d2k) which establish the above and its converse (under some technical assumptions) if $A=\frac{1}{2}I$ and $b$ is $C^\infty$. However, glancing through the proof it doesn't seem these assumptions play a fundamental role in it (then again, I only have a working knowledge--at best--of this material and I might be missing some subtleties), in fact the author states:

> **Remark**. The only property of the operator L we used was to conclude
>   q > 0. We may therefore expect a similar result for more general operators.

Does anyone know under what more general conditions the above holds? A reference with this type of results would be great.

Thanks in advance.

---

Aside: In case anyone is wondering why I even think the above should hold here's my chain of thought: If we know that the process's transition probabilities have a density $p(t,x)$, then $p$ satisfies the forward Kolmogorov equation:

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,x)=-\sum_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}[b_i(x)p(t,x)]+\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}[A_{i,j}(x)p(t,x)].$$

Suppose that we know that $X_t$ converges (in some sufficiently strong fashion) as $t\to\infty$ to some random variable $X_\infty$. Suppose that $X_\infty$'s distribution has a density $\pi(x)$. Then we have that $p(t,x)\to\pi(x)$ as $t\to\infty$. So we should have

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,x)\to 0\text{ as } t\to\infty$$

giving $(*)$. Of course, the above is totally heuristic and (I imagine) much more attention needs to be payed to the technicalities (for example, above I've assumed that the derivative of a sequence of functions is converges to the derivative of the limit of the sequence, which I suspect much depends on what fashion the sequence converges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in this reference [by arnold](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.51.1428&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on the work of R. Khasminskii over Lyapunov function method in the context of sde (especially by theroem 2.2).

Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference (I love these big-picture/historical perspective type papers). Plus it references to the book by Khaminskii which turns out to have a bunch of results (with proofs) about the content of the question--so I know where to search. If it's fine with you, I'd like to keep the question open for a bit longer in case anyone else posts another nice reference.